# In tabbar application we want to view only some view to landscape and some to portrait in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios6

In my application there are three tabs in second tab one viewcontroller in that i want to view only in portrait mode but i m not able to view in that format...so any one have right solution then answer here...

Answer (score 0):

add this methods to your second view controler :

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```